# Flat list is not working with data fetched from database

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i fetched data from server and its fetched successfully but when i try to render that data in flatlist it do not work, but when i checked Flatlist with hard coded array data its worked like normal flat list,. can you tell me what am doing wrong here ? am sharing both fetched Data Array and hard coded Array also flat list code.

---

```
This Data From Server (Database)
0: {id: "11", name: "India", image: "india.png", description: "", created_at: "2022-05-26 17:33:54"}
1: {id: "10", name: "England", image: "uk.png", description: "", created_at: "2022-05-26 17:33:54"}
2: {id: "9", name: "Nepal", image: "nepali.png", description: "", created_at: "2022-05-26 17:33:54"}
3: {id: "8", name: "USA", image: "usa.png", description: "", created_at: "2022-05-26 17:33:54"}
```

---

```
This is hard coded or assigned manually Data which works find
0: {id: 1, name: "England", source: 19}
1: {id: 2, name: "india", source: 20}
2: {id: 3, name: "Nepal", source: 21}
3: {id: 4, name: "USA", source: 21}
```

---

```
here is my Flat List Code
<FlatList
          data={dbData}
          keyExtractor={(country) => country.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item}) => (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.warn(item.name)}>
                <ServiceCard
                  source={require("../../assets/usa.png")}
                  name={item.name}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          )}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => {}}
        ></FlatList>
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are fetching the data, and the response you are getting from the API ?

Comment: Have you tried hardcode exactly same data which you fetched?

Comment: maybe you need to resolve the data to json https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json or the response data is string, then you need to parse https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: What do you mean exactly by it does not work? Are you seeing any errors at all or just no items in the list?

Comment: @yousoumar am using codeigneter 4 restfull api . here is my returning data    $countrymodel = new ServicesModel();
      $data['countries'] = $countrymodel->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll();
      return $this->respond($data);

Comment: @MikołajWittbrodt exactly how ? its in same format

Answer (score 0):

```
 <FlatList
                                    data={dbData}
                                    key={(item, index) => `${index}`}
                                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                                    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
                                    initialNumToRender={30}
                                    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
                                        {length: context.createdStrategies.length, offset: context.createdStrategies.length * index, index}
                                    )}
                                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                                        <MyStrategyElement
                                            key={index}
                                            item={item}
                                            btnText1={'Backtest'}
                                            btnText2={'Deploy'}
                                            onCreatorClick={() =>
                                            onNameClick={() =>
                                            onSecondBtnPress={() => {
                                                context.getDataToDeployStrategies(item);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                    ListEmptyComponent={() => (
                                        <MyStrategyEmptyView title={'No Strategies Present'} />
                                    )}
                                />
```